# Joining three tables (2 level) and finding sum based on conditions - SQL Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have the following schema:

```
User:
---
ID
---

Tasks:
-------------------
ID | classification
-------------------

Timesheets:
------------------------
ID  |  task_id | user_id
------------------------

TimesheetItem:
--------------------------------
ID | timesheet_id | hours | date
--------------------------------
```

Associations:

```
class User 
  has_many :timesheets
end

class Task 
  has_many :timesheets
end

class Timesheet 
  has_many :timesheet_items
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
end

class TimesheetItem
  belongs_to :timesheet
end
```

Classification can be either "Billable" or "Non-Billable".
Now I need to find for each user the sum of billable and non billable hours like this:

```
-----------------------------------
|user_id | billable | nonbillable |
-----------------------------------
```

What I did in Rails was:

```
User.joins(:timesheets, :timesheets => :task, :timesheets => :timesheet_items)
    .select("SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN tasks.task_classification = 'Billable' 
                      THEN timesheet_items.hours 
                   ELSE 
                      0 
                 END) as billable, 
             SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN tasks.task_classification = 'Non-Billable' 
                     THEN timesheet_items.hours 
                   ELSE 0 
                 END) as nonbillable")
```

But MySQL gives the error "tasks.classification" is an unknown column. This is understandable looking at the query being generated:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tasks.classification = 'Billable' THEN hours ELSE 0 END) as billable, SUM(CASE WHEN tasks.classification = 'Non-Billable' THEN hours ELSE 0 END) as nonbillable FROM `users` INNER JOIN `timesheets` ON `timesheets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `timesheet_items` ON `timesheet_items`.`timesheet_id` = `timesheets`.`id`
```

As you can see the tasks table is not being joined.

How do I achieve this? Thanks.

EDIT:

I kinda went ahead with a plain sql query that joined the tasks table to get the result since this data is used only in one place and rarely.

But now I need to group the hours by the month and find how many hours each user logged for billable and non billable hours. Eg.

Result:

```
-----------------------------------------------
user_id | month | BillableHrs | NonBillableHRS|
-----------------------------------------------
```

I have tried `group(user_id, MONTH(date))` but.. the results are weird. How can I go about getting this kind of information?

And BTW, changing the joins to :

`joins(:timesheets, :timesheets => [:task, :timesheet_items])`

solved the column not found problem :)

Ive finally arrived at this solution. ANy ideas for optimization?

```
SELECT 
  users.id as user_id,
  users.name as user_name,
  CONCAT(MONTHNAME(date)," ",YEAR(date)) as month,
  SUM( CASE 
        WHEN tasks.task_classification = "Billable" 
          THEN hours 
        ELSE 
          0 
        END ) as blb_sum, 
  SUM( CASE 
        WHEN tasks.task_classification = "Non-Billable"
          THEN hours 
        ELSE 
          0 
        END ) as nblb_sum
FROM `users` 
  INNER JOIN `timesheets` ON `timesheets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
  INNER JOIN `timesheet_items` ON `timesheet_items`.`timesheet_id` = `timesheets`.`id` 
  INNER JOIN `tasks` ON `timesheets`.`task_id` = `tasks`.`id` 
WHERE 
  timesheet_items.date >= '2013-11-1' AND
  timesheet_items.date <= '2013-11-31'
```

Comment: That's an ugly mix of activerecord and SQL -- I'd just run it as a SQL statement.

Comment: lol. yeah youre right. I was thinking of doing that. But is there any methods in AR to do case? BTW, Ill use plain SQL for this.

Comment: Hmmm, not that I know of. I'll make another suggestion as an answer though, just to see what people think of it.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions guys!! Can you help me with finding how to group sums by months? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is some pretty ugly code if it's expressed as a mixture of activerecord and SQL, one thought is to define the complex query as a view and reference that as a model.

It's pretty straightforward to do -- if this is a set of metrics at the User level, then construct a view along the lines of:

```
create view user_billing_metrics
as
select  user.id user_id,
        sum(case ... blah blah) billable_hours,
        sum(case ... blah blah) unbillable_hours
from    ...
```

Then create a readonly model ...

```
class UserBillingMetric < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :user_billing_metric

  def read_only?
    true
  end

end
```

Then ...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :user_billing_metric, :inverse_of => :user

  delegate :billable_hours  , :to => :user_billing_metric
  delegate :unbillable_hours, :to => :user_billing_metric

  def read_only?
    true
  end
end
```

You can then:

```
u = User.find( ...)

u.billable_hours
```

... or ...

```
u = User.find( ...)
hours= u.user_billing_metric
```

etc.

May have made a dumb typo in there.

A nice feature of this is that you can, for example:

```
users_to_fire = User.joins(:user_billing_metric).
                     where(:user_billing_metrics => {:billable_hours = 0})
```

Again, dumb typo possible.

It's extremely efficient to push this down to the database, much more so than trying to run this through Rails. A decent query optimiser will not evaluate expressions in the view that are not required, or even execute joins that are logically redundant.

Anyway, just floating this out for comments. I know that putting business logic in the database tier is not to everyone's taste, but it keeps it DRY, and I have situations in my own app where for performance reasons it's absolutely the only choice.

Comment: Wow. I was kinda blown away by this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
#id
class User 
  has_many :timesheets
  has_many :tasks, :through => :timesheets

  def billable_hours
    self.tasks.billable.collect{|task| task.timesheet_items_for(self)}.flatten.collect(&:hours).sum
  end

  def non_billable_hours
    self.tasks.non_billable.collect{|task| task.timesheet_items_for(self)}.flatten.collect(&:hours).sum
  end  
end

#id, classification
class Task 
  has_many :timesheets

  def timesheet_items_for(user)
    self.timesheets.for_user(user).collect(&:timesheet_items).flatten
  end

  named_scope :billable, :conditions => ["classification = ?", "Billable"]
  named_scope :non_billable, :conditions => ["classification = ?", "Non-Billable"]
end

#id, task_id, user_id
class Timesheet 
  has_many :timesheet_items
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task

  named_scope :for_user, lambda {|user| {:conditions => ["user_id = ?", user.id]} }
end

#id, timesheet_id, hours
class TimesheetItem
  belongs_to :timesheet
end
```

then in your controller, assuming you have @user defined, you can just call `@user.billable_hours` or `@user.non_billable_hours`